# Downloading a CSV from a Website Using Requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I'm a researcher trying to download some weather data from a website and I'm looking for a way to automate it using Python. I'm using Selenium and Requests libraries. The website looks like this:

[image: Website with weather information]

Clicking the csv button in the top right corner takes me to a new web page which automatically downloads the csv. I've been able to access this with the code, but I have yet to be able to store the csv.

```
csv_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"csv")
    print("CSV clicked ;)")
    csv_button.click()
    url = csv_button.get_attribute('href') 
# the url it takes you to when you click submit. Opening this automatically downloads the csv. This works
    
    
    response = requests.get(url)


    ## Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        
        # Specify the file path where you want to save the CSV
        file_path = '/Users/me/Documents/meteo-test.csv' # Generic file path

        # Open the file in binary write mode and write the content
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:

            file.write(response.content) # This does not write the csv. I think this is the error
```

Instead of writing a csv file, it appears to me that it just writes a bunch of html. This is what the file looks like with the current code
[a sample of the file the current code is writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLuQ.png)

I have very little experience with Selenium and Requests, so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong, or if there's some easy function that will fix everything.

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: The url comes from https://pro.meteofrance.com but it requires login information to access the weather information.

Comment: What is the contents of the file? Is it empty? Try `print(response.content)`. What is the result?

Comment: Also, you might be making this more complicated than necessary with selenium. If the URL is always the same or if you can build it from some data (such as a date range), you can remove the selenium code and just use requests.

Comment: Also, check `response.status_code`. For example, you can do `print(response.status_code)`. Is it a 200? If not, what is it? If it's 400-499, then you are making the request incorrectly. My guess is that it is a 401 or 403 which means you haven't correctly "logged in" with your script.

Comment: The content you show in the screenshot is HTML. It probably has an error message. Rename the file with a `.html` extension then open it in your web browser to read it.

Comment: You could also open the file in a text editor such as Visual Studio Code. Then you can read the HTML directly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice For response.status_code I'm getting 200. As for response.content, I'm getting b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<!--[if lt IE 8]>\r\n<html class="ie lt10 lt9 lt8" lang="fr"> ...basically the html I shared in the screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the information. It looks like the URL you are attempting to use gives HTML, not a CSV. You should rename the CSV file to .html to be able to easily open it in your browser and see what it is.

Comment: Another thing to check is what the button is actually doing. You can investigate this by opening the website in your browser and right clicking on it. This will open a pane in your browser called the developer tools. From there you can dig into the HTML and DOM elements rendered in the page. Another tool you can use is the Network tab in this pane. Click on this tab and then click on the CSV button. You can see what request the browser makes. Double check that the URL is the same as what your script is using. Also check what verb the request uses. Is it a GET? Or is it POST or something else?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I looked at the html file and it seems pretty useless. It just has a couple buttons that say "close", none of which work, as well as a link to "contact", which also doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is earlier in your code than you think. The URL you get with `url = csv_button.get_attribute('href')` doesn't give you the CSV file like you think it does. One possible solution is to click the button like you are and let selenium give you the download without requests. Another possible solution is to figure out how to give the URL directly to requests without using selenium. A third possible solution is to figure out why you aren't getting the correct URL from the CSV button.

Comment: Another question...is what you showed here your entire script? Or do you have other code to login with this service using selenium? If you are doing that as well and didn't show it here, then requests doesn't know you are logged in. Or more accurately, requests doesn't have all of the information it needs to tell the service that you are logged in. So you will probably need to figure out that part, but either just using selenium to download the file directly or to provide the correct authentication credentials to requests so it can download the file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That is my problem! Requests doesn't have the correct login info! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexFischer It's really strange that requests.get() returns a response with status_code 200 when you aren't logged in. It should be a 401. But that might be because this isn't a REST API and the URL just returns some HTML that is intended to be used directly in a browser.